# OpenLayer Coordinate System

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoding, openlayers

I'm struggling to understand the coordinate system used by OpenLayers.

Leicester, UK is at approx.

```
Latitude:  52.63973017532399
Longitude: -1.142578125
```

But to display the same location using OpenLayers I have to use:

```
Latitude:  6915601.9146245
Longitude: -125089.1967713
```

e.g:

```
var center  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-125089.1967713, 6915601.9146245);
var map     = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
map.setCenter(center, 12);
```

These are clearly not Latitude-Longitude coordinates, is there some conversion I need to take account of?

A working example is http://craig-russell.co.uk/demos/openlayers/so_map.html

Answer (score 9):

It looks like I do need to map between coordinate systems.
This is done with the `transform()` function like so:

```
var coor_from = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var coor_to   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
var center    = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-1.142578125, 52.63973017532399);
var map       = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
center.transform(coor_from, coor_to);
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
map.setCenter(center, 12);
```

Answer (score 3):

Now it is possible to do:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
var p = map.getView().getProjection();
var cord = ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude], p);
```

Comment: It is also possible to omit the projection: `ol.proj.fromLonLat([longitude, latitude])`. In that case the default is Web Mercator.